# Doctrine ODM / MongoDB : in AND in queries

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I'm using Doctrine ODM with mongoDB.

I'm trying to do queries like :

```
$queryBuilder->field('array_field')->in('even_value_1', 'event_value_2');
$queryBuilder->field('array_field')->in('odd_value_1', 'odd_value_2');
```

The idea is to select all documents that have in their

```
array_field(event_value_1 OR event_value_2) AND (odd_value_1 OR odd_value_2)
```

With the syntax I'm using, I'm getting the documents that have

```
event_value_1 OR event_value_2 OR odd_value_1 OR odd_value_2
```

Any ideas on how to proceed or if it is possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the $and operator is just not currently available in MongoDB.
The $and operator is in 1.9.1 (unstable version)

Here is the ticket for the feature request : 
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1089

Currently (1.8.x) the only solution seems to use multiple "$or" statments like  :

```
even_value_1 AND odd_value_1 
OR even_value_1 AND odd_value_2
OR even_value_2 AND odd_value_1
OR event_value_2 AND odd_value_2
```

EDIT: Here is some code to help future users

First, we need a function to transform our

```
array_field(event_value_1 OR event_value_2) AND (odd_value_1 OR odd_value_2)
```

to

```
even_value_1 AND odd_value_1 
OR even_value_1 AND odd_value_2
OR even_value_2 AND odd_value_1
OR event_value_2 AND odd_value_2
```

Here are the needed functions

```
/**
 * $pArray for our example should be like array(array(event_value_1, 
 *                 event_value_2),array(odd_value_1, odd_value_2))
 */
function transform_and_group_of_or_to_or_group_of_and ($pArray)
{
    //Make sure we have sequential numerical indexes
    sort($pArray);

    $maxIndices = array();
    foreach ($pArray as $key=>&$values){
        //Make sure we have sequential numerical indexes
        sort($values);

        $maxIndices[$key] = count($values)-1;
        $arIndices[$key] = 0;
    }

    $groupCount = count($pArray);
    $groupOfAnd = array();

    do {
        $newGroup = array();
        for ($i=0; $i<$groupCount; $i++){
            $indice = $arIndices[$i];
            $sousTab = $pArray[$i];
            $newGroup[] = $sousTab[$indice];
        }
        $groupOfAnd[] = $newGroup;
    } while(increment_numbers($arIndices, $maxIndices));

    return $groupOfAnd;
}

function increment_numbers(& $arIndices, $maxIndices){
    //Raise the last indice
    $arIndices[count($arIndices)-1]++;

    $check = true;
    for ($i=count($arIndices)-1; (($i>=0) && ($check === true)); $i--){
        if ($arIndices[$i] > $maxIndices[$i]){
            if ($i > 0){
               $arIndices[$i-1]++;//increment the upper indice element
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
            $arIndices[$i] = 0;
            $check=true;
        }else{
            $check = false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

For the Doctrine ODM part :

```
    if (count($arGroupedCritere)) {
        $arGroupedCritere = transform_and_group_of_or_to_or_group_of_and($arGroupedCritere);
            foreach($arGroupedCritere as $arCritere) {
                $queryBuilder->addOr($queryBuilder->expr()->field('_criteres')->all($arCritere));
            }
    }
```

Hope this helps